# Prove that A-B=A ⇔ A⋂B=Φ

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Another question from my 11th grade Mathematics textbook. I actually proved it but I still want to confirm if it's right or not. Please check it out :

```
In order to prove that A-B=A ⇔ A⋂B=Φ, we will first prove that A-B=A ⇒ A⋂B=Φ and then we'll prove 
that A⋂B=Φ ⇒ A-B=A
First part : Proving that  A-B=A ⇒ A⋂B=Φ :-
    Let x be an arbitrary element of A
    So, x ∈ A
    Since A=A-B, so x ∈ A-B
    So, x ∈ A and x ∉ B
    This means that for an arbitrary element of A, it is not an element of B
    So, A and B are both disjoint sets
    So, they have no element in common
    So, A⋂B=Φ
    So, A-B=A ⇒ A⋂B=Φ

Second part : Proving that A⋂B=Φ ⇒ A-B=A :-
    A-B = A-(A⋂B)
    Since A⋂B = Φ, so, A-B = A-Φ = A
    So,  A⋂B=Φ ⇒ A-B=A

So, A-B=A ⇔ A⋂B=Φ
Hence, proved
```

Let me know about any flaws in this proof, even the slightest, especially if the proof can be made shorter and if I have included anything unnecessary in it.

Thanks :)

Comment: Have you proven in a previous exercise or seen proven in a previous example that $A\setminus B = A\setminus (A\cap B)$?  If not, that seems like it is missing some details.

Comment: Your proof of the first direction has a bit of redundancy but is overall correct and well written.  Specifically, the three statements `So, A and B are both disjoint sets`,
`So, they have no element in common`, `So, A⋂B=Φ` say exactly the same thing. That said: if we're allowed to use the fact that `A-B = A-(A⋂B)` (as you do in the second part), then we could make this first part much quicker.

Comment: @JMoravitz No, that part hasn't come yet...

Comment: The "quicker proof" for the first part, by the way, would be as follows.

Suppose that $A-B = A$. Since $A - B = A - (A \cap B)$, we have 
$$
A - (A \cap B) = A.
$$
Suppose for the purpose of contradiction that $(A \cap B)$ is non-empty.  Let $x$ be an arbitrary element of $A \cap B$. Since $x \in A$ and $x \in B$, we know that $x \in A$.  However, $x$ is not an element of $A - (A \cap B)$, which is equal to $A$. This is a contradiction.

Conclude that $A \cap B$ is empty.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thanks, I'd like to know how the first part can be made shorter with application of facts such as  A-B = A-(A⋂B), but, this fact wasn't something that I saw being used in previous examples of proofs for various theorems, I just figured this out myself by picturing it in the form of Venn Diagrams...

Comment: I am concerned with the use of $A - B = A - (A \cap B)$. It is too strong a result to be using for this question. With it the answer is trivial : the first way, if $A -B  = A$, then $A - (A \cap B) = A$, but $A \cap B \subset A$, so if $x \in A \cap B$ then $x \in A$ but $x \notin A - (A \cap B)$, a contradiction to the equality. Hence, $A \cap B$ is empty, no $x$ can be contained in it. The other way is as you mentioned. I feel you should avoid use of this equality.

Comment: Whoa people, I just began sets three days ago, I'm gonna be honest here, I didn't understand much of the last two comments. I just thought of A-B = A−(A∩B) by figuring it out from Venn Diagrams, that's it

Comment: How shall I prove the second part without the use of A-B = A−(A∩B) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a proof for the second part: suppose that $A \cap B = \emptyset$.  It is clear that $A - B \subseteq A$, so we show that $A \subseteq A - B$.
Let $x$ be an arbitrary element of $A$.

- So, $x \in A$.
- Since $A \cap B$ is empty, $x \in A$ and $x \notin A \cap B$.
- So, $x \in A$ and it does not hold that ($x \in A$ and $x \in B$).
- Equivalently, $x \in A$ and it does not hold that $x \in B$.
- So, $x \in A - B$.

So, $A \subseteq A-B$, which is to say that $A - B = A$ as was desired.

Comment: Thanks, it was really helpful, but I have one more query, sir. I'm just not able to come up with some proofs like these by myself. Is it because I'm new to sets? I was able to prove almost all Trigonometric identity related questions in y textbook pretty soon, also how long ago did you learn set theory?

Comment: Is it just practice that would enable me to construct all these proofs?

Comment: Yes, it really is just about practice.  The counterintuitive step of this proof was to write $x \in A$ and $x \notin A \cap B$, since saying that $x \notin \emptyset$ clearly doesn't tell us anything about $x$.  This step is, however, a neat solution to the question of "how do we use the fact that $A \cap B = \emptyset$?"

Comment: Thank You, would practice more now :)

Comment: Regarding your comparison with trig identities: although they have a lot more pieces that need to fit together, trig identity proof tend to be straightforward in the sense that the next step is almost always some sort of simplification.  The introduction of "and $x \in A \cap B$" is analogous to "adding and subtracting" or "multiplying and dividing by" some quantity.  Those steps (though routine in some contexts) are always counterintuitive the first time you see them

Comment: i agree, Trig Identities just need a Mathematical Ability, whereas Set Theory requires more logic, and that too, in each step, I guess that';s why a lot of children face problems with Set Theory at first. I thought I was facing it because  my mind wasn't too mathematically mature for it (btw, I just gave my 9th grade finals). Thanks again, I'm loving this website...